# Jaspersoft Studio: Upgraded the java version from 8 to 11. But facing Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class issue

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I have upgraded the java version from jav 1.8 to java 11. I want to learn Jasper reports but facing issue with Build Path of the report.

Error:
`JRE System Library [JavaSE-11] (unbound)`

when i edit and click on it the error i am getting is `Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class`

Please refer the screenshots attached.How to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]